# GAM plot in R for "by = factor"

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have a dataset of dolphin encounters (count data) which are segregated by "type" of detection of an event (acoustic, visual, mix). I ran a GAMM to test the effect of environmental variables on the number of encounters. I have the following code:

```r
s1 <- gam(encounters ~ s(dist, k= 5, by = type) + 
          s(depth, k= 5, by = type) + 
          s(timeenc, k= 5, by = type) + s(boats, k= 5, by = type) + 
          te(swell, bft, k= 3, by = type) + type + 
          s(line, bs= "re") + offset(log(lineseg)), family = tw(), 
          method = "REML", data = sousa_full)
```

When I plot the model, I naturally get three plots for each variable, showing their effect of the number of encounters within the detection type category.

[image: GAM plot]

Is there a way to make a single plot for each variable which represents all three graphs? I'm using `mgcViz` for plotting and very new to the whole thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `itsadug` package makes this process really simple for GAMMs. Below is some simplified and annotated code from the [vignette on plotting](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/itsadug/vignettes/overview.html). First I load the libraries, attach the data that will be used for the model, and fit the GAMM.

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(itsadug)
library(mgcv)
data(simdat)

#### By Factor Smooth GAMM ####
m2 <-  bam(Y ~ Group + s(Time, by=Group)
           + s(Subject, bs='re')
           + s(Subject, Time, bs='re'),
           data=simdat)
```

To plot the by-factor smooths on top of each other, we have to "grab" the information with the `get_modelterm` function for each group:

```
#### Get By-Smooth Terms for Plots ####
st1 <- get_modelterm(m2, select=1)
st2 <- get_modelterm(m2, select=2)
```

Then you create an empty space to overlay the smooths onto the plot:

```
#### Create Empty Space for Plot ####
emptyPlot(2000, # x ranges from 0 to 2000
          c(-15,10), # y ranges from -15 to 10
          h=0, # horizontal line at 0
          main='s(Time)') # title
```

Then you just add the lines with their standard errors shaded onto the plot:

```
#### Overlay Smooths ####
plot_error(st1$Time, # plot x values 
           st1$fit, # plot y values
           st1$se.fit, # use this standard error 
           shade=TRUE) # add color shading

plot_error(st2$Time,
           st2$fit,
           st2$se.fit,
           shade=TRUE,
           col='red',
           lty=4, 
           lwd=2) # same here but for second group
```

Finally a legend can be added:

```
#### Add Legend ####
legend('bottomleft', # legend location
       legend=c('Children', 'Adults'), # labels
       fill=c(alpha('black'), alpha('red'))) # fill colors for legend
```

Which gives you this plot in the end:

[image]

If you want to make a more elegant, customized `ggplot2` style plot, then the [`gratia` package](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/articles/custom-plotting.html) offers a lot of options too.

Comment: Thankyou!! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will now explore how to make this pretty in gratia.

Answer (score 5):

By default, plotting a fitted GAM with **`mgcv`** invisibly returns the data used for plotting. You can save these to create your own custom plots. E.g.:

```
## Data preparation
isit <- read.csv("ISIT.csv")
isit$Season <- factor(isit$Season)

## Fit GAM with by smooth
library("mgcv")
fact_int <- gam(Sources ~ Season + s(SampleDepth, by = Season) +
                  s(RelativeDepth), data = isit, method = "REML")

## Default plot
inp <- plot(fact_int) ## creates three plots
str(inp[[1]]) ## plotting data is saved in a list, with a list for each smooth term

## Create matrix for custom plot
z <- 1.96
mat <- cbind(inp[[1]]$fit, inp[[1]]$fit - z*inp[[1]]$se, inp[[1]]$fit + z*inp[[1]]$se,
             inp[[2]]$fit, inp[[2]]$fit - z*inp[[2]]$se, inp[[2]]$fit + z*inp[[2]]$se)

## Create custom plot
cols <- rep(c("red", "blue"), each = 3)
matplot(x = inp[[1]]$x, mat, type = "l", lty = c(1,2,2,1,2,2), col = cols,
        xlab = "SampleDepth", ylab = "s(SampleDepth)")
```

[image: A GAM plot with two smoothing spline curves with confidence intervals]

Dataset and GAM specification are from https://r.qcbs.ca/workshop08/book-en/preparing-for-the-workshop.html.